# Liferay and Oracle DB

Tags: tomcat, java, oracle, cms

I'm installing liferay community edition with an Oracle database, I managed to get it running with the user SYSTEM, but I don't like this... I want to create another user in another tablespace, the problem is that it seems that liferay needs to create tables and alter them according during its lifetime.

Do you know what permission and roles need to be assigned to the user?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful using the `USERS` tablespace. It's not technically good practice, but it will work fine.

Here's what I use and it works pretty well.

```sql
CREATE TABLESPACE LPORTAL7 DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/data/liferay_01.dbf' SIZE 2G AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
CREATE USER LPORTAL7 IDENTIFIED BY <password> DEFAULT TABLESPACE LPORTAL7;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW TO LPORTAL7;
ALTER USER LPORTAL7 QUOTA UNLIMITED ON LPORTAL7;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Oracle install normally has a USERS tablespace. If you are happy with that, try

CREATE USER liferay IDENTIFIED BY password DEFAULT TABLESPACE users QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE VIEW TO liferay;

That might be sufficient. If the setup script errors, then other permissions may be required.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be working, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: FYI: The extra permissions are only required during installation or update (or deployment of new plugins) - during the "normal" runtime, only the standard operations SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE are required.